# I'm trying to run service on my IIS 7.5 but it is giving HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, iis-7.5

I'm trying to run a service on my IIS 7.5 but it is giving following error.
[image]

help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Okay, 500 Internal Server Error. Config Error on Line 15, it said.

Comment: how to resolve this issue? I'm new to wcf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the app_pool is set to the same .net version as your application. Sometimes it isn't.

Comment: thanks, version was different, i updated it using nu get package manager and it worked. :)